# How to upload, rename and download files?

Tags: javascript, html, image, rename

I would like to rename some (ok, I admit - unfortunately quite a few) of my files (png's). I haven't found a suitable program and I'm sure that the whole thing must be possible with html+js as well.

My idea is to upload several files at once and rename them using a table (see below).

The snippet is everything, how far I have come so far, because obviously my code doesn't really work: The files are damaged after the download and moreover not in a single folder, but as many different files.

```
let table = {
   "file0": "myFirstFile",
   "file1": "mySecondFile",
   "file2": "myThirdFile",
   "file3": "myLastFile"    
}
```

> Renaming "file0.png" -> "myFirstFile.png", and so on...

---

```js
let table = {
  "test1.png": "new1",
  "test2.png": "new2"
}

$("input[name='file']").on("change", function() {
  for (let i = 0; i < this.files.length; i++) {
    let blob = this.files[i].slice(0, -1, 'image/png');
    let oldName = this.files[i].name;
    let newName = table[oldName.substr(0, oldName.lastIndexOf("."))] + ".png"
    let file = new File([blob], newName, {
      type: 'image/png'
    });
    download(file)
  }
})

function downloadURI(file) {
  var link = document.createElement("a");
  link.download = file;
  link.href = file;
  link.click();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Run as Webserverver <b>python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000</b><br> -------------------------
<br><br> Select files: <input type="file" name="file" multiple>
<br>
<a onclick="saveFiles()" style="color: blue">Download images</a>
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: **EDIT**: I'd like to upload a bunch of files that should get renamed. Afterwards the files will be downloaded again.

Comment: To upload, place your input type file in a form, and submit that. You will need some server side code to save file on server.

Comment: Why? Will a web server not do this job?

Comment: Well, it has to know where to save the files.

Comment: In the download folder... A simple task for a simple web server \^_^/